# Is there a way to associate XML Tags with blocks of properties?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, properties, formatting

For XMLSerialization, You use XML Tags to indicate how a property/field is to be added in the serialization.

Its ugly having an XML tag for each property. I understand the value of having the explicitness, but its a pain on the eyes

My question is there a method to do something like this, where a tag is associated with a block?

```
public class Application : IApplication
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string StoreLink { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Build { get; set; }
    public bool IsDebug { get; set; }
    public bool IsX86 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apperently you can do...

```
[XmlAttribute] public string Version;
[XmlAttribute] public string Number;
```

Which is a bit easier on the eyes.